# Trying to print specific pages (not continous) using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and it works fine. However now I am trying to print double sided and it work fine when its pages 2-3 or 5-6 but when I try to use pages 5 and 7 it prints only single sided.

```
Sub thursday()

On Error GoTo errHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'add "Candy Room", "Dry Stock" if needed

Worksheets("Conc temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 1
Worksheets("Conc temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 8
Worksheets("Conc count and waste").PrintOut
Worksheets("OT temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 1
Worksheets("OT temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 8
Worksheets("OT count and waste").PrintOut
Worksheets("Poptopia temp and cleaning").PrintOut
Worksheets("Poptopia count and waste").PrintOut
Worksheets("Lobby Check").PrintOut
Worksheets("Xscape Check").PrintOut
Worksheets("Auditorium Check").PrintOut from:=1, to:=3
Worksheets("Washroom Check").PrintOut from:=2, to:=2
Worksheets("Auditorium Check").PrintOut from:=4, to:=5
Worksheets("Washroom Check").PrintOut from:=1, to:=1
Worksheets("Washroom Check").PrintOut from:=3, to:=3
Worksheets("Auditorium Check").PrintOut from:=6, to:=11
Worksheets("Washroom Check").PrintOut from:=6, to:=6
Worksheets("Washroom Check").PrintOut from:=4, to:=4
Worksheets("Auditorium Check").PrintOut from:=12, to:=13
Worksheets("Washroom Check").PrintOut from:=5, to:=5
Worksheets("Auditorium Check").PrintOut from:=14, to:=16
Worksheets("Stock count and opening").PrintOut
Worksheets("Print buttons").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
errHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Trying to have a code so that I can print the following;

```
Worksheets("Conc temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 1
Worksheets("Conc temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 8
```

with only one code line, which will execute the print command with both those pages at once and will print double sided.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the printer properties in the sub. Best advice is search therought he MSDN Microsoft website it is crazy helpful. Try adding these to your code.

```
<SerializableAttribute>
Public Class PrinterSettings
    Implements ICloneable

Public Property Duplex As Duplex
```

If you are still stuck checkout the website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: with that added on all the continuous pages are printing double sided, however the

Worksheets("Conc temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 1
Worksheets("Conc temp and cleaning").PrintOut 'print 8

still prints one sided since it is executing the page 1 first and then page 8. Unless I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try encapsulating the printout pages in a "With" Statement? My syntax might be a bit off but something like.  `With Worksheets("").printout  <br/> code  <br/> Worksheets("Print buttons").Activate  <br/> End With`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the following to make things work the way I wanted them to. Made sure the print settings are set to duplex for all the sheets I wanted printed double sided and then used either one of the following;

Worksheets (Array("Sheet1 ,Sheet2").PrintOut

Or

Worksheets ("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$I$43, $J$54:$H63" 
Worksheets ("Sheet1").PrintOut
Worksheets ("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

Hopefully this helps anyone else if they are trying to do the same thing, and thanks Ben for helping out :)